# Paypal IPN: notify_url is never called

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm creating an online shop and all seems to be good but my specified `notify_url` seems to not get called after the payment succeeded.

```
<?php
echo "
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
<input type='hidden' value='$price' name='amount' />
<input name='currency_code' type='hidden' value='EUR' />
<input name='shipping' type='hidden' value='0.00' />
<input name='tax' type='hidden' value='0.00' />
<input name='return' type='hidden' value='$nddaff/refill.php' />
<input name='cancel_return' type='hidden' value='$nddaff/refill.php' />
<input name='notify_url' type='hidden' value='http://domain.com/validationpaypal.php' />
<input name='cmd' type='hidden' value='_xclick' />
<input name='business' type='hidden' value='test-facilitator@gmail.com'/>
<input name='item_name' type='hidden' value='$name' />
<input name='custom' type='hidden' value='id=$id&type=$type' />
<input name='lc' type='hidden' value='FR' />
<input name='bn' type='hidden' value='PP-BuyNowBF' />
<input name='sub' value='Buy Now - $price"."€' type='submit' /></form>";
?>
```

Comment: if its not working with code then try to use directly from business account setting as you can follow this URL for settings : http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/paypal-ipn-notify-url-not-working-sandbox-account/

Comment: @Albert Akki There must be a thing wich is wrong in my code if its works for others

Comment: Try using the simulator so you can see what the IPN code receives https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/

Comment: I've already try with it and it worked fine with

Comment: Have you checked IPN History in the PayPal account?

Comment: The problem is not necessarily here. The URL could be down, or inaccessible, or return an error rather than invoking your script, or your script might start and fail without logging its own execution. You need to consider all the possibilities, not just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**

There were a bug in paypal sandbox yesterday, all works fine today !

Thanks all for helping !